# Way client service register 2 time with eureka server?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, replication, netflix-eureka

2023-10-22 22:35:37.903  INFO 14426 --- [nio-9030-exec-2] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance client service:api-gateway-service:8090 with status UP (replication=false)
2023-10-22 22:35:38.520  INFO 14426 --- [nio-9030-exec-3] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Registered instance client service :api-gateway-service:8090 with status UP (replication=true)

---

eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false

add above property in application.property file of eureka server

---